# Vim completion with YouCompleteMe on windows

Tags: c++, vim, vim-plugin

I am desperately trying to get [YouCompletMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/) working on windows, the author clearly says that there is no official support for windows so that's fair enough. Though there is [a wiki](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Windows-Installation-Guide) to build it on windows and you find 1/2 people online claiming they succeded in building it on windows without semantic support for C/C++...

I was wondering if I could use the compiled `ycm_core.pyd` from someone else or if for obvious reasons that would not work.

I am using `vim7.4 (I have both 32/64 bit versions) + python2.7 + python3.2`

Comment: Did you try to contact those successful people?

Comment: Unfortunatley I found only 2, and both have done it too long ago (YCM ask me to recompile so back to square 1)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can download archives of drop-in YCM plugin containing binaries (`ycm_core.pyd`) from me: **[Vim YouCompleteMe for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/Alexander-Shukaev/vim-youcompleteme-for-windows)**. Both x86 and x64 architectures are provided.

If you also need bleeding-edge LLVM/Clang, you can download the binaries from me as well: **[LLVM for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/Alexander-Shukaev/llvm-for-windows)**. Both x86 and x64 architectures are provided.

If you are looking for up-to-date Vim with Python support, you can download the binaries from me once again: **[Vim for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/Alexander-Shukaev/vim-for-windows)**. Both x86 and x64 architectures are provided, as well as support for both Python 2 (which is required by YCM) and Python 3 altogether.

### Common Pitfalls

---

1. Don't forget to have Python 2 DLL (e.g. `python27.dll`) and Python 2
   Interpreter (`python.exe`) in the `PATH` environment variable;
2. Don't forget to have `libclang.dll` in the `PATH` environment
   variable (recommended) **OR** right next to `ycm_core.pyd`;
3. Make sure that architectures of all 3 components (LLVM/Clang, Vim,
   YCM) match;
4. You can find some hints on configuration in **[my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801354/c-family-semantic-autocompletion-plugins-for-vim-using-clang-clang-complete-yo/18876388#18876388)**.

Comment: You might want to add links to your binaries on the YCM Windows wiki page: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Windows-Installation-Guide

Comment: Looks like your [links](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-youcompleteme-for-windows) are broken.

Comment: @AlexanderShukaev, is it just me or the links are broken again?

Comment: You can find them in the downloads section: https://bitbucket.org/Alexander-Shukaev/vim-for-windows/downloads

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the accepted answer (SE won't let me comment), I got  Alexander Shukaev's binaries from here:
https://bitbucket.org/Alexander-Shukaev/vim-youcompleteme-for-windows/downloads

(in case the links on the other page are still broken).

Comment: this should be in comment

Comment: @Usman--agreed, but it's my first post in SE and it says I must have 50 reputation to comment (on others' posts).  You could upvote me to help me get there faster :).

Comment: Can I also increase my reputation by stating the obvious and criticizing things that were already addressed in the answer?