# C-family Semantic Autocompletion Plugins for Vim (C/C++ completion) using Clang (clang_complete, YouCompleteMe)

Tags: vim, autocomplete, clang, clang-complete, libclang

I am using 64-bit Vim on windows, [this version](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-for-windows/src#markdown-header-downloads) by [Haroogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743860/):

```
+python27
+python33
+huge
```

I am trying to use [clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete), so I took the `libclang.dll` library [here](https://code.google.com/p/rxwen-blog-stuff/downloads/list) and I set up my `vimrc` correctly. `libclang.dll` is found.

However when I open a `*.cpp` file I now have a message:

> `libclang` cannot find the builtin includes this will cause slow
>   completion code

but I have no completion at all...

I found [this post](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/issues/238) with the guy who build the version of Vim that I use, but there is no clear instruction about what to do. Can anybody help here?

### UPDATE

Here is what I did:

1. Took [Vim YouCompleteMe for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-youcompleteme-for-windows/downloads)
2. Took [LLVM for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/llvm-for-windows/src)
3. Took the liclang.dll from it and stuck it in YCM python directory
4. Took [.ycm_extra_conf.py](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py) and stuck it with my cpp file

It almost work (I do not have any error message), but I still get:
[image: no auto]

Comment: Why don't you simply continue the thread until the problem is resolved? That's what issue trackers are for.

Comment: No, [it isn't.](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/issues/238)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### clang_complete

---

Thanks for using **[Vim for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/Alexander-Shukaev/vim-for-windows)**, hope you enjoy.

To solve your problem you have to utilize `.clang_complete` file. Read more about it in `:h clang_complete`. In brief, you can put this file into the root directory of any of your projects (i.e. for each project this file can be different, what perfectly makes sense, since different projects have different toolchain configurations). Here is the sample for MinGW-w64 toolchain:

```
-ID:/Toolchains/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++
-ID:/Toolchains/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32
-ID:/Toolchains/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/backward
-ID:/Toolchains/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include
-ID:/Toolchains/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed
-ID:/Toolchains/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include

-ID:/Libraries/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/Boost/1.54.0/include

-ID:/Libraries/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/Qt/4.8.5/include

-ID:/Libraries/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/Eigen/3.1.3/include

"-ID:/Libraries/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/Example with Spaces/0.0.1/include"

-std=c++11

-DUNICODE
```

When you are editing some file in the project with Vim, `clang_complete` traverses backward all the parent directories of the edited file until it stumbles across the first `.clang_complete` file to read. Then it reads all these flags/switches/definitions and uses them during the invocation of `libclang` for completion.

### YouCompleteMe

---

These days, I don't use `clang_complete` anymore. There is more powerful semantic autocompletion plugin for Vim our there. It's **[YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe)**. I highly recommend you try it out. For semantic completion of C-family languages (C/C++/Objective-C/Objective-C++) it uses `libclang` as well. It relies on a robust C++ back end, and is therefore incredibly fast. It has great integration with **[syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic)** (another must have plugin for Vim). It has an ability to jump to definitions, and so on.

Since it's written in C++ and glued to Vim via Python, you'd have to compile the C++ back end. To ease the pain you can download prebuilt and ready to use YCM plugin from my **[Vim YouCompleteMe for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/Alexander-Shukaev/vim-youcompleteme-for-windows)**. I've built it for both x86 and x64 architectures. The native component is called `ycm_core.pyd`. As usual the architecture of the Vim build you chose has to match the YCM build (i.e. `ycm_core.pyd`). YCM can work **ONLY** with Python 2 (not 3), so just make sure that you have Python 2 DLL (e.g. `python27.dll`) and Python 2 Interpreter (`python.exe`) in the `PATH` environment variable.

If you need LLVM/Clang, you can download it from me as well: **[LLVM for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/Alexander-Shukaev/llvm-for-windows)**. Again, just make sure that you have `libclang.dll` in the `PATH` environment variable (recommended) **OR** right next to `ycm_core.pyd`. Once again both x86 and x64 architectures are supported, and once again the architecture should match both Vim's and YCM's ones.

Concerning completion:

> Should he magically find where is the STL?

Of course not! This is just an autocompletion system based on Clang front end. How is it supposed to know which toolchain you're currently using to compile your code? You could use anything: Visual C++, Borland C++, GCC, MinGW, MinGW-w64, LLVM/Clang, etc. Each of them has their own standard library and runtime supplied. Thus, in each case you'd have to specify all the paths which your current toolchain uses to find standard includes.

For example, in case of GCC, MinGW, MinGW-w64, you can run the following in POSIX shell:

```
g++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null
```

Or in Windows Command Prompt:

```
g++ -E -x c++ - -v < nul
```

And look for the following excerpt:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 d:\toolchains\x64\mingw-w64\4.8.1\posix\seh\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++
 d:\toolchains\x64\mingw-w64\4.8.1\posix\seh\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 d:\toolchains\x64\mingw-w64\4.8.1\posix\seh\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/backward
 d:\toolchains\x64\mingw-w64\4.8.1\posix\seh\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include
 d:\toolchains\x64\mingw-w64\4.8.1\posix\seh\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed
 d:\toolchains\x64\mingw-w64\4.8.1\posix\seh\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
```

This tells you all the paths to standard includes which GCC, MinGW, MinGW-w64 use **implicitly** during compilation of your code.

For LLVM/Clang, you can do the same:

```
clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null
```

Or:

```
clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < nul
```

When you know the paths, you can happily add them into `.ycm_extra_conf.py`. For instance, in my case:

```
'-I',
'D:/Toolchains/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/POSIX/SEH/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++',
'-I',
'D:/Toolchains/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/POSIX/SEH/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32',
'-I',
'D:/Toolchains/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/POSIX/SEH/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/backward',
'-I',
'D:/Toolchains/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/POSIX/SEH/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include',
'-I',
'D:/Toolchains/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/POSIX/SEH/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed',
'-I',
'D:/Toolchains/x64/MinGW-w64/4.8.1/POSIX/SEH/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include',
```

Comment: It works perfectly!!! thank you so much, I think I should write something summarizing what you made me do. BTW I used `clang++` from LLVM I took from you but that did not work, then I took `mingw64` and it worked perfectly... What about having vim-YCM on github so that we can Vundle it ? Anyway I'll write the stuff down and may be advertize it to Val Markovic. Bounty on the way

Comment: If you mean that you tried to use Clang to compile your code, then of course it didn't work. Clang is not yet ready for production on Windows. Even the standard library and runtime are not fully ready for Windows. That's why for now you better stick with either MSVC, MinGW, or MinGW-w64 on Windows. From what I remember, one can Vundle from Bitbucket too. Investigate this and tell me later. If there is no chance to Vundle from Bitbucket, then I'll mirror it on Github too. Thanks again for testing.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, I did not know clang was not ready for windows. I'll come back to you about bitbucket. Can you please remove the previous comments to clean the post? Thanks again

Comment: @AlexanderShukaev Thank you for the post! After hours of trying to set up the flags, I found your answer, and autocompletion finally works! And its wicked fast!