# Vim with YouCompleteMe and Markdown

Tags: vim

I got vim and the youcompleteme plugin working under windows. [For details take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693526/vim-completion-with-youcompleteme-on-windows)

Is it possible to use it "not only" for coding but also for writing/editing markdown documents. If so, what do I have to do?

Comment: What do you expect from YouCompleteMe when writing markdown documents? Did you find anything in the documentation?

Comment: I looked up the documentation but not sure if it is possible what i'm looking for. I want to trigger YouCompleteMe after the first 3 chars e.g. doc (will show up e.g. documentation as expanding possibility). It would be nice if YouCompleteMe would assist my personal laziness... But only for the text elements already listed in the markdown file.

Answer (score 10):

Clear the YCM blacklist in your .vimrc:

```
let g:ycm_filetype_blacklist = {}
```

Answer (score 3):

The default value is:

```
g:ycm_filetype_blacklist={'notes': 1, 'markdown': 1, 'unite': 1, 'tagbar': 1, 'pandoc': 1, 'qf': 1, 'vimwiki': 1, 'text': 1, 'infolog': 1, 'mail': 1}
```

Setting this value in **.vimrc**.